# Permutations in an Infinite List of Random Numbers

Tags: probability, random, chaos-theory

In an infinite list of random numbers from a to b, prove that in this list, there are all possible permutations of n numbers from the list, where n can be any number. Here are some versions of the problem in context:

"Every phone number in the world appears among the decimal places of pi... and if you converted the numbers to letters, you'd find every book that's ever been written or will be written." (from *Think of a Number*, by Johnny Ball)

"Consider Coin Man, who makes decisions based on the flip of a coin. Let's say that if he flips heads, he moves one step up the page, and if he flips tails, he moves a step down the page... if we imagine that at a certain distance from the starting point in one direction there is a barrier, there is a 100 per cent chance that eventually Coin Man will hit the barrier." (from *Alex's Adventures in Numberland*, by Alex Bellos)

For the first version, how do we know that it contains every phone number or book in the world? For the second version, how do we know that Coin Man will hit the barrier? I can sort of visualise it, but I'd really like a rigorous proof.

*Edit:* "Does Ball actually say that "Every phone number in the world appears among the decimal places of pi"? People think this is likely, but it's not known to be true. You can't believe everything you read. (It is true for "almost every" number in place of π.)" - a commenter. Maybe this is true, in which case, you can simply ignore the first example. Or, where pi is mentioned, just think of any infinite sequence of digits.

Comment: Does Ball actually say that "Every phone number in the world appears among the decimal places of pi"? People think this is likely, but it's _not_ known to be true. You can't believe everything you read. (It _is_ true for "almost every" number in place of $\pi$.)

Comment: Yes, that's a direct quote from the book. To me, it actually seems plausible if with the second example about Coin Man is there, too, because it's the same sort of problem - the digits of pi could be said to be random, like Coin Man's sequence of heads and tails. However, I'll add your comment to my original post, because you may well be right.

Comment: Anyone can think of anything any way they want, but the digits of $\pi$ are _not_ random.

Comment: I know, but in this context, it doesn't really matter. Besides, you could say that the coin tossing is not random, as it depends on the way the hand moves, how much air resistance there is, and so on. As I said in the edit, just think of an infinite list of random numbers where the quote talks about pi.

Comment: The second question is a classic random walk question.  You can imagine being on an infinite integer number line, and let $A$ be the event of _eventually_ visiting a location that is one step to the right of your current position.  Let $p=P[A]$. Then $$p=\underbrace{P[A|\mbox{next move left}]}_{p^2}(1/2) + \underbrace{P[A|\mbox{next move right}]}_{1}(1/2) $$ So $p=(1/2)(p^2+1)$ and the only answer is $p=1$.  We eventually move to that location with probability 1.  And once we do, we eventually move to the right of that with probability 1, and so on.

Comment: @Michael I see. So I wonder how we could incorporate that into the proof about the list of random numbers.

Comment: @J843136028 : I think you mean the first sentence of your question.  I did not understand that sentence, so I do not know what precisely it wants to prove. What do you mean by "random numbers from $a$ to $b$"?  Are $a$ and $b$ integers?  real numbers?  What is the distribution, and are these numbers chosen indepenently?  The statement about $\pi$ in the Ball book seems like an over-claim, see the Ulrich answer for clarifications on that.

Comment: @Michael What I meant was that you could have numbers from 1-10, or 1-5, and by n random numbers, I meant you could have three, six, or any number numbers in a row. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes, if you have an infinite list of random integers that are independently and uniformly chosen in the set $\{1, 2, ..., 10\}$, and if you consider any particular sequence of $n$ numbers in $\{1, ..., 10\}$ (say, $\{3, 3, 4, 2, 2\}$ with $n=5$), then with probabiltiy 1 that sequence will be in your list.  The Ulrich answer says exactly this and gives a nice proof.

Answer (score 1):

The statement about the digits of $\pi$ is not known to be true.

But the corresponding statement *is* true for a random sequence of digits. Say we're looking for the sequence 1243. That could be the first four digits, or the next four digits... Probability problems with "and" are often easier than problems with "or". Say the sequence 1243 does *not* appear in out random sequence.

That means the first four digits are not 1243, *and* the next four digits are not 1243, *and* the four digits after that are not 1243... The probability of each miss is $9999/10,000$. So the probability that we miss infinitely many times is the infinite product $$(9999/10,000)(9999/10,000)\dots=0.$$

Comment: What do you mean by 'The statement about the digits of $\pi$ is not known to be true.' ? Do we know whether the decimal digits of $\pi$ are random or not?

Comment: What do you mean, what do I mean? I meant exactly what I said. The digits of $\pi$ are clearly _not_ random. That's so clear that it's also clear that it can't be what you really meant to ask. What I suspect you meant to ask was whether the digits of $\pi$ are known to be "normal" (that would mean that on average a tenth of the digits are $0$, etc.) That's not known.

Comment: Okay, I thought you said the statement is known to be not true but I guess what you actually said we don't know whether the statement is true, right (I am not very good at English)?

Comment: But, of course, to say that event has zero probability does not mean to say that it cannot happen ;-) Also, what is "not known to be true" is whether the sequence of digits contains any arbitrary (undetermined but finite length) subsequence. But if we restrict to phone numbers, it might be another story, because here we have a maximum length and we can check by brute force. For example, the first 250M digits contains all numbers of length up to 7 https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-length-of-the-shortest-string-of-digits-that-doesnt-appear-in-the-first-10-000-000-digits-of-pi

Comment: @leonbloy No, of course probability zero does not imply impossible. That's far from the only technicality I decided it was best to elide in the present context. Now, I didn't know that about the seven-digit numbers. Luckily phone numbers have ten digits, heh...

Comment: "Luckily phone numbers have ten digits, heh." Well, that depends on the country. Here (Argentina) we have 8, and in some cities even less https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan#Variable-length_dialing

Comment: @leonbloy Surely "all phone numbers" includes all the phone numbers on the planet (at least), regardless of which country.

Comment: @leonbloy: I downloaded the first billion digits and checked for $8$-digit numbers (the standard in Germany) -- $99995573$ of them occur, with $4427$ missing, close to the expected $4540$. If I can find the second billion to download somewhere, only $0.2$ of them would be expected to be missing; but I haven't found them yet.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question :

An irrational number $x$ is called a 'normal number' if for any natural number $n$ with $m$ digits, the density of $n$ in the decimal digits of $x$ is $\frac{1}{10^m - 10^{m-1}}$ in all bases (i.e. you see every natural number (with the same number of digits) in the decimal digits the same time). It is a conjecture that whether $\pi$ is a normal number or not and we don't know much about the normal numbers (the first example of a normal number is $0.123456789101112...$ and it is found much after the definition of a normal number).

For the second question :

Law of large numbers states that if an event is possible then it'll eventually happen if you make the experiment sufficiently. There is a possibility that Coin Man hits the barrier thus it'll eventually happen if he flips so many times.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why this has anything to do with the law of large numbers - how do we know that Coin Man hasn't just flipped tails every time?

Comment: Because LLN says it is impossible. There is a possibility that Coin Man flips a head, thus if he flips again and again, he will flip a head.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm asking is, is there always a _finite_ number of times Coin Man would have to toss before flipping a head?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you flip a head after an infinitely number of experiments? Of course Coin Man will flip a head after a finite number of times Coin Man tosses a tail (by definition of tossing a head). But of course this finite number is not a constant.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: The LLN does not directly apply here, as it is not enough to say we eventually get heads.  This is more a random walk problem.

Comment: What I mean is if you toss a coin $1000$ times, most probably you'll get a head. If you don't, then try $10000$ times. Soon or later, you'll get a head.

Comment: @Michael you are right but I thought LLN implies what I say, isn't it?

Comment: @Levent : LLN certainly implies that you will eventually flip a head, in fact it implies the fraction of flips that are heads converges to $1/2$ with prob 1.  But that statement does not imply you eventually move to the location one step to the right of you (if the flips are periodically Tails, Heads, Tails, Heads, and so on, then you are always either in your initial position or one step to the left of it, and you never visit one step to the right of your initial).  That typically does not happen, but you need another argument to show that.

Comment: Well, but you have a chance to flip Tails Tails (which converges to $1/4$ with probability $1$) thus it is impossible to toss Tails and Heads periodically and I think LLN directly implies that.

Comment: @Michael That's why I didn't understand Levent's comment. Thanks!